# Concordance with line numbers

Tags: python

Write a program that creates a concordance file - an index that tells you on which line of the file each word appears.   Call the function concord, and accept the input file name as an argument.  Write the output to a file called concord.txt.  If a word is on more than one line, the concordance will show you all of the lines containing that word.   Hint:  Use a dictionary keyed by each word to solve this problem, e.g.

Input file contains:

```
I went to the restaurant yesterday.  Hello, I said, to the man who
greeted me at the door.  Where is your restroom?  On my way to the
restroom, I bumped into the waiter boy.  Excuse me, sir, I said.
When I returned to the table, the meal was served.  These are the
best clams I have ever eaten, I said.  My compliments to the chef.
Unfortunately, I was arrested by the officer for not paying my bill.
```

Produces:

```
clams  [5]
   is  [2]
 chef  [5]
 ever  [5]
   at  [2]
 have  [5]
table  [4]
 your  [2]
 best  [5]
  sir  [3]
 said  [1, 3, 5]
  for  [6]
  boy  [3]
 when  [4]
   by  [6]
   to  [1, 2, 4, 5]
  way  [2]
  was  [4, 6]
  ...
```

L08-8)  (5 points)
Same code as above, but words in the concordance should be sorted when you print them.

I have this so far, but it gives me the number of times the word appears not the line numbers.

Python Code:

```
def main():
   """
       Main function
   """
   try:
       # Opening file for reading
       fp = open("d:\Python\input.txt");

       # Dictionary to hold words and their frequencies
       wordDict = {};

       # Reading data line by line
       for line in fp:
           # Splitting words on space
           words = line.split(" ");

           # Looping over each word in words
           for word in words:

               # Considering only the words with length at-least 1
               if len(word) > 0:
                   # Converting to lower case
                   word = word.lower();

                   # Checking for existence of key in dict
                   if word in wordDict.keys():
                       # If already present, just update frequency
                       wordDict[word] += 1;
                   else:
                       # If new word, updating existing value
                       wordDict[word] = 1;

       # Closing file
       fp.close();

       # Looping over sorted keys of dictionary
       for key in sorted(wordDict):
           # Printing word frequency values
           print(" {0} : {1} ".format(key, wordDict[key]));

   except Exception as ex:
       # Handling exceptions
       print(ex);

# Calling main function      
main();
```

Comment: Semi-colons are not a Python thing, are you aware?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please make a [mre]. The description and code you posted do a bunch of things that aren't relevant to the question, like reading and writing to text files. As a replacement for reading a file, you could use a list of strings for example. BTW [ask] has some more helpful tips.

Comment: "it gives me the number of times the word appears not the line numbers." Do you understand the code? Can you, for instance, point out how the code keeps track of the number of appearances? So replace that with a part that keeps track of which lines the word was on. Hint: in the `wordDict`, use a list for the values instead of an int; the elements of the list will be the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a dictionary where the keys are the words and the values are the lines the words are on:

```
s = """I went to the restaurant yesterday. Hello, I said, to the man who
greeted me at the door. Where is your restroom? On my way to the
restroom, I bumped into the waiter boy. Excuse me, sir, I said.
When I returned to the table, the meal was served. These are the
best clams I have ever eaten, I said. My compliments to the chef.
Unfortunately, I was arrested by the officer for not paying my bill."""

def main():
    words = {}
    lines = [i.lower() for i in s.split("\n")]
    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split():
            w = word.strip(" ,.!?")
            words[w] = [i for i, l in enumerate(lines, start=1) if w in l]

    for w, n in words.items():
        print(w, n)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because one-liners are cool.

```
s = """I went to the restaurant yesterday. Hello, I said, to the man who
greeted me at the door. Where is your restroom? On my way to the
restroom, I bumped into the waiter boy. Excuse me, sir, I said.
When I returned to the table, the meal was served. These are the
best clams I have ever eaten, I said. My compliments to the chef.
Unfortunately, I was arrested by the officer for not paying my bill."""

words = {word.lower().strip(' .,!?'): [l_n+1 for l_n, l in enumerate(s.split('\n')) if word.lower().strip(' .,!?') in [w.lower().strip(' .,!?') for w in l.split()]] for line in s.split('\n') for word in line.split()}
```

For readability:

```
words = {
    word.lower().strip(' .,!?'): [l_n+1 for l_n, l in enumerate(s.split('\n')) 
                                  if word.lower().strip(' .,!?') in [w.lower().strip(' .,!?') 
                                                                     for w in l.split()]]
    for line in s.split('\n')
    for word in line.split()
}
```